# In-memory etcd storage

Tags: storage, latency, etcd

I'd like to run etcd on k8s with in-memory storage. We are using etcd to store just temporary data, and there's no problem losing them in case pod(s) restart.

We are using for etcd deployment Helm chart `bitnami/etcd`. Is it possible to configure it, so we would be able to deploy `/var/lib/etcd` as `tmpfs` and not k8s PVC?

Our VMware storage is incredibly slow, and it's causing problem with fdatasync within etcd cluster. So, at least until we will have fast SSD storage, in-memory storage would be solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can turn off persistence and use an `EmptyDir`:

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/etcd/README.md

set `persistence.enabled: false`